# Error on shiny server on corporate computer

Tags: proxy, shiny, digital-ocean, enterprise, shiny-server

I have managed to correctly deploy a shiny server using an Ubuntu DigitalOcean droplet.

You can find it at 46.101.40.217:3838

The example page works fine on my personal laptop and mobile, while I get the following error when I try to access it from my work network, as you can see from the next image [error on shimy server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vezZP.png)

Do you think it is the company's proxy or should I configure further since the work computer is a windows one? Are there workarounds/solutions to this problem?

Thanks.

Davide

Comment: all the `scripts` in [hello-example](http://46.101.40.217:3838/sample-apps/hello/) are blocked by work network, so output of `iframe` is not visible, also check [shinyproxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/)

Comment: ask your IT  to change firewall settings, open port 3838 for the incoming traffic?